# Can I limit the parameter of an inherited method in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a class extending the node `EventEmitter`.  But I want to limit the event that can be registered.

```
class Foo extends EventEmitter {
  on(event: 'myEvent', listener: Function): this;
  emit(event: 'myEvent', ...args: any[]): boolean
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.on('wrongEvent', ()=>{}); // this should cause compiling error
```

Is this achievable?

I'm getting error:

```
t.ts(6,3): error TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
t.ts(7,3): error TS2391: Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
t.ts(10,8): error TS2345: Argument of type '"wrongEvent"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"myEvent"'.
```

How can I prevent the TS2391 error?

Comment: TS2391 just says that implementation is missing, so implement it.

Comment: As for limiting parameter type - you can try [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks! In this case, I would like to use the implementation in the parent class.  Is it doable?

Comment: yes, you should call the base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself according to @AlekseyL.'s comment

```
class Foo extends EventEmitter {
  on(event: 'myEvent', listener: Function): this {
    return super.on(event, listener);
  };
  emit(event: 'myEvent'): boolean {
    return super.emit(event);
  }
}
```